# How to uniquely identify users in a Twilio VOIP App

Tags: twilio, voip

I am trying to develop a VOIP app using Twilio. Each user using my app will be able to call other users using VoIP only (No phone numbers). I can see how the workflow goes but:

With SIP, each user must have a SIP account to uniquely identify themselves. In Twilio, they say they do not offer SIP registration services. **So how would I be able to uniquely identify users and connect them to each other? And How Would I be able to register them using their unique app id?**

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

One of the steps in the Twilio Client workflow is requesting a capability token. The capability token indicates whether or not a particular Client can make outgoing calls or receive incoming calls.

In a typical workflow, a Twilio Client app will make a request to your web server for a capability token and pass in the client name they wish to use (for instance, `alice`). When you create the capability token you can specify that `alice` is able to receive incoming calls. Later, when you want to place a call to `alice` you can refer to `alice` as shown  [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#example-2).

For more on how the entire process works, you might want to check out the [Twilio Client quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client) if  you haven't already.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome. I think I have a fairly good picture on where to go. Can I use the user id from my application (an integer as a string) as my client name?